# Ajax form submitting twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My Ajax form is submitting twice for some reason even using `preventDefault()` and `return false`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form_codes").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            data: $('#form_codes').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{url('save_code')}}',
            success: function(msg) {
                         $('#product_codes > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + $('#code').val() + '</td><td>' + $('#description').val() + '</td></tr>');
                         $('#code').val('');
                         $('#description').val('');
                     },
            error: function(msg) {

                   }
        });         
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And you have only 1 form in your HTML with `id="form_codes"` right?

Comment: maybe it has to do with your click event

Comment: Your question is missing context but i guess you are just calling this snippet twice

Comment: quick test, try to comment this part to check if the ajax call will continue to execute, I guess u pasted this code twice in your file.

Comment: could you include which part you submit the form not just the event listener submit

Comment: any errors in your console? does the page refresh when posted? is this code after the form or withihn document ready?  Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: My bad, using the blade templating engine I was yielding my script twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to the submit event, as it prevents every other event from executing so this may stop the second form submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#form_codes").submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    $.ajax({
                        data: $('#form_codes').serialize(),
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '{{url('save_code')}}',
                        success: function(msg) {
                            $('#product_codes > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + $('#code').val() + '</td><td>' + $('#description').val() + '</td></tr>');
                            $('#code').val('');
                            $('#description').val('');
                        },
                        error: function(msg) {

                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in my blade template engine i was yielding my script twice (effectively including it twice.)

The function works fine and only submits once now.